# Simulating realistic button presses

Tags: fpga, vhdl, debounce

I need to simulate realistic button presses that include bounce patterns..but digitally with something like an FPGA to test my debouncing code. How do I generate those noises?

Comment: Why not test it by pressing a button?

Comment: I need to test it for a lot of buttons..something that I can do by running a script

Comment: How about a relay?

Comment: I suppose you could use a DAC. But seems like more trouble than its worth.

Comment: On board? Use a real button.

Comment: Just make a bouncy signal.  "button <= '1', '0' after 100 us, '1' after 5 ns, '0' after '7' ns", etc.

Answer (score 2):

The press of a button is not really noise, they are mostly at the logic level of either 0V and VDD.

When bounce occurs, it would bounce a few times between VDD and GND, but there is not really much transient noise, or they appear because of the acquisition speed of the oscillo.

[image]

You can take a button and record a few presses on an oscilloscope, and then program the pattern in your FPGA.

If you really want to make transient peaks, you can add a small cap on the line and generate very short pulses.

Comment: currently I'm able to generate very small pulses of periods in the range of microseconds but the pulses that don't go up to VDD are the ones I can't generate and the noise around the edges

Comment: Damien - Hi, That image seems to have come from somewhere else, so in order to comply with [this site rule](/help/referencing), can you edit your answer and add a link back to the original source web page, please? Thanks :-)

Comment: @BabaYaga you can add a simple RC filter on the pin and with short pulses you can do the ones that don't go to VDD.